# How to return author of emoji's name in discord,js?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So, I am making a userinfo command and I found the `emoji.author` property. I tried some things as `emoji.author.user.tag` to return the author of the emoji, but still didn't get anything.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

[`GuildEmoji`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildEmoji)'s [`author`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildEmoji?scrollTo=author) property returns a [`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User) object, so you can use either `emoji.author.tag` or `emoji.author.username`.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to [fetch](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildEmoji?scrollTo=fetchAuthor) the author.

```js
const userTag = (await emoji.fetchAuthor()).tag;
```

Don't forget that you can only use `await` inside an [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

Comment: @UchihaPedro If I answered your question, click the checkmark (✓) to accept the answer. You can take a look at [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: srry but actually u didnt, btw my friend helped me

Comment: In that case, you can post a new answer, which you believe solves your problem better than mine or Zsolt's. And mark your answer as accepted. That way other people will know what helped you the best. When they encounter a similar problem.